# How to mock external program call in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mocking

In my Java web Spring application, I have to call external program. Those are not some REST API call but some system binary on the file system.

How can I unit test/mock those calls efficiently?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear — I don’t get what you are asking.

Comment: Abstract the call inside `class MyExternalBinary`; then mock that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to think in *abstractions*.

Example: you could create something like

```
interface BinaryRunner {
   void runBinary(String command, String... args); 
}

class BinaryRunnerImpl implements BinaryRunner { ...
```

( of course, this is only an example; as I completely left our the error handling path )

And your "production" code uses that to, well, run binaries. And now you can mock an instance of BinaryRunner and give that to your production code. Your production code makes its calls; and you can use the mock to check on that.

Finally: of course, testing the implementation of the BinaryRunner might be a little bit harder ;-)